# Reactive form validation for dynamic and hidden fields

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, validation, angular-reactive-forms

First off, I have an Angular reactive form that has a button that can add another `FormArray` to the form. All validation good and working as expected. Things have gotten a little tricky when introducing another dynamic control to the already dynamic form group. This control is shown/hidden based on a selection made in another form control.

When the control is shown I introduce validation, when the control is hidden the validation is cleared. This ensures that my form remains valid/invalid correctly.

Its acting a little buggy e.g. when I complete a group of inputs and add another dynamic group of inputs, both triggering the hidden control... then to amend the previous hidden input - the form remains true. e.g.
[image]

Selecting `123` triggers the "Other Code" control, removing the value should make the form invalid, but it stays true at this point.

I have a change function assigned to the select to determine whats been selected.

```
      selectClick(x) {
            const f = this.form;
            let items = this.form.get('justificationItems') as FormArray;
            if (x === '123') {
                items.controls.forEach(i => {
            console.log(i)
                    i['controls'].other.setValidators([Validators.required]);
            //      i['controls'].other.updateValueAndValidity();
                });
            } else {
                items.controls.forEach(i => {
                    i['controls'].other.clearValidators();
                //  i['controls'].other.updateValueAndValidity();
                });
}
        f.updateValueAndValidity();
    }
```

I suspect when changing the select property to trigger the above it does not do it to the correct index item, and it does it for all?

StackBlitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-prepopulate-dynamic-reactive-form-array-ufxsf9?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best way to "clear/add Validators" really is enabled or disabled the formControls. Remember a formControl has as status one of this:

```
 type FormControlStatus = 'VALID' | 'INVALID' | 'PENDING' | 'DISABLED';
```

So we can simple enabled/disabled the FormControl. Futhermore, when we create the formGroup we can created disabled, so at first will be **not INVALID**

Well, the code is a bit confussed. first the use of i['controls'].other (really you can use `i.controls.other` an a estrange mix using FormBuilder and new Form.

As always we has a FormArray we create a getter

```
  get justificationItems()
  {
    return this.form.get('justificationItems') as FormArray;
  }
```

In stead use two differents functions to create the form, we can use and unique

```
  createJustificationField(x: any=null): FormGroup {
    x=x || {name:null,description:null,code:null,other:null}
    return new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl(x.name, [Validators.required]),
      description: new FormControl(x.description, [Validators.required]),
      code: new FormControl(x.code, [Validators.required]),
      other: new FormControl({value:x.other,
                  disabled:x.code!=='123'},[Validators.required]),
    });
  }
```

See that we can use as

```
this.createJustificationField(..an object..)
this.createJustificationField()
```

Our functions: `createForm`, `addItem` and `selectClick` (I like more another name like `codeChange` but is a minor change) becomes like

```
  createForm() {
    this.service.getmodel().subscribe((response:any) => {
      this.form = new FormGroup({
        justificationItems: new FormArray(
                  response.justificationItems.map(x=>
                        this.createJustificationField(x))
        ),
      });
    });
  }

  addItem(): void {
    this.justificationItems.push(this.createJustificationField());
    this.form.updateValueAndValidity();
  }


  selectClick(x,i) {
    if (x === '123') 
      this.justificationItems.at(i).get('other').enable()
    else
      this.justificationItems.at(i).get('other').disable()
        
    this.form.updateValueAndValidity();
  }
```

And the .html becomes more clear in the way

```
<form *ngIf="form" [formGroup]="form">
  <div formArrayName="justificationItems">
    <div
      *ngFor="
        let orgs of justificationItems.controls;
        let i = index;
        let last = last
      "
      [formGroupName]="i"
    >
      <label>Name </label>
      <input formControlName="name" placeholder="Item name" /><br />
      <label>Description </label>
      <input
        formControlName="description"
        placeholder="Item description"
      /><br />
      <label>Code </label>
      <select
        (change)="selectClick($event.target.value, i)"
        formControlName="code"
      >
        <option value="123">123</option>
        <option value="456">456</option></select
      ><br />
      <ng-container *ngIf="justificationItems.at(i).value.code === '123'">
        <label>Other Code </label>
        <input formControlName="other" placeholder="other" /><br /><br />
      </ng-container>
      <button
        *ngIf="last"
        [disabled]="justificationItems.at(i).invalid"
        type="button"
        (click)="addItem()"
      >
        Add Item
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button [disabled]="!form.valid" type="button">Submit</button>
</form>

<p>Is form valid: {{ form?.valid | json }}</p>
```

see the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-prepopulate-dynamic-reactive-form-array-rhjx9u?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: What a great comprehensive answer! I knew you could use disable but the way I was adding disable it still kept its validation for some reason.

Comment: See that when you add a formGroup, the form is not valid because the formGroup has `name`, `description` and `code` that has `Validators.required`

Answer (score 1):

Root cause: When `selectClick` trigger, you clear or set validation for all controls `other` in array form. You should set only for one form in formArray.

I rewrite your function:

```
selectClick(x, index) {
    const f = this.form;
    let items = this.form.get('justificationItems') as FormArray;
    if (x === '123') {
  items.controls[index]['controls'].other.setValidators([Validators.required]);
    } else {
        items.controls.forEach(i => {
            items.controls[index]['controls'].other.clearValidators();
            i['controls'].other.updateValueAndValidity();
        });
    }
items.controls[index]['controls'].other.updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

change code in template:

```
<select
      (change)="selectClick($event.target.value, i)"
      formControlName="code"
    >
```