# Angular clear validators of formArray

Tags: angular

How can i clear validators for the formArray that i have inside my formGroup?

here is my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-material-starter-yqme4t?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

**.ts**

```
  this.createEstimation = this.fb.group({
  name: ['', Validators.required],
  surname: ['', Validators.required],
categories: this.fb.array([this.initCat()]),
   });

  initCat() {
    return this.fb.group({
      carPartCategory: ['', Validators.required],
      carPartSubCategory: ['', Validators.required],
      quantity: ['', Validators.required],
      comment: [''],
    });
  }
```

**what i tried and didn't worked:**

```
  (this.createEstimation.controls['categories'] as FormArray).controls.forEach(c => c.clearValidators());
  (this.createEstimation.controls['categories'] as FormArray).controls.forEach(c => c.updateValueAndValidity());

   (this.createEstimation.controls['categories'] as FormArray).clearValidators();
   (this.createEstimation.controls['categories'] as FormArray).updateValueAndValidity();

  (<FormArray>this.createEstimation.get('categories')).controls.forEach(c => c.setErrors({required: null}));
  (<FormArray>this.createEstimation.get('categories')).controls.forEach(c => c.updateValueAndValidity());
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: your formArray is a FormArray of FormGroups (you can has FormArray of FormControls and FormArray of FormGroups or a FormArray of FormArray), so this.createEstimation.controls['categories'].controls are the "formGroups", not the controls of the formGroup (in your case you only has one formGroup in the FormArray). BTW really I feel that it's better enable/disable a FormControl that clearValidators, see, e.g. this [another SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71222366/reactive-form-validation-for-dynamic-and-hidden-fields/71223876#71223876)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clean the validator for every control and, reset the value to update the status form.

```
clearValidations(): void {
    const controlKeys = Object.keys(this.form.controls);
    controlKeys.forEach((controlKey) => {
      const field = this.form.controls[controlKey];
      field.clearValidators();
      const currentValue = field.value;
      field.setValue("fakeValue");
      field.setValue(currentValue);
    });
}
```

I hope I've helped you